# Information about how to use OneNote in Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, onenote

Can somebody help me where I can find information about how to use OneNote in Sharepoint?

Regards,
Jan

Answer (score 0):

In case if you're using SharePoint modern site, Go to Shared Documents, which is available in the leftside pane of your teamsite page. From there, click on New and then OneNote notebook to create new OneNote for the site.

If you're struggling in get into the Shared Documents page, form the url like the following format and you will get directly to that page :

```
https://{{tenantname}}.sharepoint.com/sites/{{sitename}}/Shared Documents
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a team site, modern or classic, it will automatically create a Notebook linked to this site. You can access this Notebook via the Quick Launch.

You can also create a notebook in the OneNote client application and then share it to the SharePoint site.

References:

[Share a notebook on a SharePoint site.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/share-a-notebook-on-a-sharepoint-site-2f5f2721-08e4-49a3-ba4e-6e63f92da529)

[Microsoft SharePoint is the Best Home for OneNote.](https://bitwizards.com/thought-leadership/blog/2016/september/microsoft-sharepoint-is-the-best-home-for-onenote)

[OneNote – the Team Site Notebook.](https://www.kalmstrom.com/Tips/SharePoint-Online-Course/OneNote.htm)